# xmlsec is broken in new version due to __init__.pyi file

Tags: python, xmlsec, pyi

I was using `xmlsec` in my project, which was using latest release, with new release today, it's failing.

```
              # .tox/unittest/bin/pip install xmlsec
              Collecting xmlsec
                Using cached xmlsec-1.3.7.tar.gz (59 kB)
                Installing build dependencies ... done
                Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
                Installing backend dependencies ... done
                  Preparing wheel metadata ... done
              Collecting lxml>=3.8
                Using cached lxml-4.5.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (5.5 MB)
              Building wheels for collected packages: xmlsec
                Building wheel for xmlsec (PEP 517) ... error
                ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
                 command: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cicd-pipeline-myprj-prtest/.tox/unittest/bin/python /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cicd-pipeline-myprj-prtest/.tox/unittest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmp2y9wnyqo
                     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-4nrsprc3/xmlsec
                Complete output (60 lines):
                running bdist_wheel
                running build
                running build_py
                package init file 'src/xmlsec/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
                creating build
                creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
                creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/xmlsec
                copying src/xmlsec/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/xmlsec
                copying src/xmlsec/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/xmlsec
                copying src/xmlsec/template.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/xmlsec
                copying src/xmlsec/constants.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/xmlsec
                copying src/xmlsec/tree.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/xmlsec
                running build_ext
                building 'xmlsec' extension
                creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
                creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/tmp
                creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/tmp/pip-install-4nrsprc3
                creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/tmp/pip-install-4nrsprc3/xmlsec
                creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/tmp/pip-install-4nrsprc3/xmlsec/src
                gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO=openssl -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO_DYNAMIC_LOADING=1 -D__XMLSEC_FUNCTION__=__FUNCTION__ -DXMLSEC_NO_SIZE_T -DXMLSEC_NO_GOST=1 -DXMLSEC_NO_XKMS=1 -DXMLSEC_DL_LIBLTDL=1 -DMODULE_NAME=xmlsec -DMODULE_VERSION=1.3.7 -I/usr/include/xmlsec1 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/tmp/pip-build-env-55iapbjz/normal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lxml/includes -I/tmp/pip-build-env-55iapbjz/normal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lxml -I/tmp/pip-build-env-55iapbjz/normal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lxml/includes/libxslt -I/tmp/pip-build-env-55iapbjz/normal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lxml/includes/libxml -I/tmp/pip-build-env-55iapbjz/normal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lxml/includes/libexslt -I/tmp/pip-build-env-55iapbjz/normal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lxml/includes/__pycache__ -I/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cicd-pipeline-myprj-prtest/.tox/unittest/include -I/var/lib/jenkins/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/include/python3.7m -c /tmp/pip-install-4nrsprc3/xmlsec/src/enc.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/tmp/pip-install-4nrsprc3/xmlsec/src/enc.o -g -std=c99 -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-error=declaration-after-statement -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Os
                /tmp/pip-install-4nrsprc3/xmlsec/src/enc.c: In function ‘PyXmlSec_ClearReplacedNodes’:
                /tmp/pip-install-4nrsprc3/xmlsec/src/enc.c:186:14: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
                         elem = PyXmlSec_elementFactory(doc, n);
                              ^
                gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO=openssl -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO_DYNAMIC_LOADING=1 -D__XMLSEC_FUNCTION__=__FUNCTION__ -DXMLSEC_NO_SIZE_T -DXMLSEC_NO_GOST=1 -DXMLSEC_NO_XKMS=1 -DXMLSEC_DL_LIBLTDL=1 -DMODULE_NAME=xmlsec -DMODULE_VERSION=1.3.7 -I/usr/include/xmlsec1 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/tmp/pip-build-env-55iapbjz/normal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lxml/includes -I/tmp/pip-build-env-55iapbjz/normal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lxml -I/tmp/pip-build-env-55iapbjz/normal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lxml/includes/libxslt -I/tmp/pip-build-env-55iapbjz/normal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lxml/includes/libxml -I/tmp/pip-build-env-55iapbjz/normal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lxml/includes/libexslt -I/tmp/pip-build-env-55iapbjz/normal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lxml/includes/__pycache__ -I/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/cicd-pipeline-myprj-prtest/.tox/unittest/include -I/var/lib/jenkins/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/include/python3.7m -c /tmp/pip-install-4nrsprc3/xmlsec/src/lxml.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/tmp/pip-install-4nrsprc3/xmlsec/src/lxml.o -g -std=c99 -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-error=declaration-after-statement -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Os
                In file included from /tmp/pip-install-4nrsprc3/xmlsec/src/lxml.c:13:0:
                /tmp/pip-build-env-55iapbjz/normal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:266:14: warning: ‘lxml_unpack_xmldoc_capsule’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
                 static void* lxml_unpack_xmldoc_capsule(PyObject* capsule, int* is_owned)
```

When I check for detail error, it was `package init file 'src/xmlsec/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)`. Where in latest release today, it was changed to `__init__.pyi`.

[https://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec/blob/1.3.7/src/xmlsec/**init**.pyi](https://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec/blob/1.3.7/src/xmlsec/__init__.pyi).

How to handler this `pyi` file ?

Comment: `package init file not found or not a regular file` is not an error, only a warning and doesn't fail the build. What is the actual issue? I don't see any build error in the log. `pyi` files are no-ops and only to aid the developer by providing type hints in the IDEs.

Comment: Can you run `.tox/unittest/bin/pip install xmlsec -vvv` and add the full log to the question or some service like pastebin?

Comment: seems like they fixed in new version `1.3.8`

Answer (score 0):

They fixed in new version https://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec/pull/142

Install 1.3.8, and it should work.